# Unable to call the function inside the .dll file of Trace32?

Tags: debugging, trace32

This is my remote dll file location.
t32api = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\Users\xxxxxx\Downloads\t32api64.dll')`

From the below code snippet, I am not getting any functions like T32_Config / Config

```
# Configure communication channel
t32api.T32_Config(b"NODE=",b"localhost")
t32api.T32_Config(b"PORT=",b"20000")
t32api.T32_Config(b"PACKLEN=",b"1024")

t32api.T32_Exit()
```

[image]

By using this code, I am not able to communicate with the Hardware(Licensed).
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your error code / message?

Comment: If you are using Python to interact with Trace32, there is a module provided by Lauterbach that you can install, so you won't need to use the C API.